# How to omit error messages in JSON output in ffprobe?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffprobe

While fetching the stream details with ffprobe getting `Input buffer exhausted before END element found` error. ffprobe gives the requested info but the error is included in the output and creates invalid JSON.

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height:stream_tags=rotate -of json testVideo.mp4

{
[aac @ 0x7fc06201cc00] Input buffer exhausted before END element found
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640,
            "tags": {

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How to prevent error messages in the JSON output when using ffprobe?

Here is the video link [testVideo.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uq4gnDrqmltHgR2zcYqjtIYDTODrQ2RB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: won't work as it is still gonna throw an error and I know I can use -loglevel quite here but using that will keep the others error as well quite which I don't want. I just need a way so I can fix the clip audio steam itself while running the same command.

Comment: Yes, the video players are able to play the video properly.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uq4gnDrqmltHgR2zcYqjtIYDTODrQ2RB/view?usp=sharing
here is the video

Comment: I don't see a problem here. It's still giving you the requested info despite the error.

Comment: yes does gives the info but while consuming it as JSON creates an issue i get this error within that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Redirect stderr

The JSON is output to *stdout*. The error is output to *stderr*. Both are being printed in the console output. You can redirect the stderr output so it does not get included in the console output.

```
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height:stream_tags=rotate -of json testVideo.mp4 2> error.log
```

## Ignore errors

This error is not preventing you from getting the requested data, so you can ignore it. Use `-loglevel quiet` / `-v quiet` to silence errors to prevent them from being included in the output.

```
ffprobe -loglevel quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height:stream_tags=rotate -of json testVideo.mp4
```

The downside compared to redirecting is that you may miss important errors.

Comment: yes, that helps thanks @llogan so when we redirect if it doesn't get included in the console output is it not gonna be the same for other errors which might be important ?

Comment: @puneetjain All stderr output, including any errors, is being output to `error.log`. The log gets overwritten each time. If you prefer to append use `2>> error.log`.